# How I can detect when other control changes it bounds?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a custom `TLabel` that in principle can be attached to any other visual component in the form. The component has a property `position` which tells where it will be positioned towards the attached control (left, above, etc.). This works fine when the related control is attached, and the component positions itself according to the `position` property.

Problem is that I can't make the component detect when the related control changes it bounds so it can properly reposition itself. I guess that has to do with `WMMove` and `WMResize`. How can I do for the related control to notify the `TLabel` that any of the bounds properties has changed?

Comment: Is it a TControl or a TWinControl? That is, does it have a window handle or not? I think you almost need to think about making a TPanel that can contain your associated controls.  Your `TLabelFollowingOtherControl` can be managed by the `TSmartLayoutPanel` which can watch all the controls inside it, and know when they move. I seriously don't think I would want a TLabel doing all kinds of gross hooks into the form that owns it.  Look at how Swing does layout management (Java) to gain some inspiration.

Comment: If the parent of your `TLabel` component  is going to be a `TControl` descendant, you can intercept its  `WindowProc` method while you'll be assigning to it. In such intercepted `WindowProc` method you can then watch for the `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` message for instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A control's `OnResize` event is triggered whenever its position and/or dimension changes.  So one simply solution is to assign a handler to that event when you attach your Label to a control, eg:

```
private
  FControl: TControl;

// OnResize is protected in TControl so use an accessor class to reach it...
type
  TControlAccess = class(TControl)
  end;

procedure TMyLabel.Destroy;
begin
  SetControl(nil);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyLabel.SetControl(AControl: TControl);
begin
  if FControl <> AControl then
  begin
    if FControl <> nil then
    begin
      TControlAccess(FControl).OnResize := nil;
      FControl.RemoveFreeNotification(Self);
    end;
    FControl := AControl;
    if FControl <> nil then
    begin
      FControl.FreeNotification(Self);
      TControlAccess(FControl).OnResize := ControlResized;
    end;
    ...
  end;
end;

procedure TMyLabel.Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation);
begin
  inherited;
  if (Operation = opRemove) and (AComponent = FControl) then
    FControl := nil;
end;

procedure TMyLabel.ControlResized(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // reposition as needed...
end;
```

Of course, this will cause issues if the user wants to assign their own `OnResize` handler to the control.

The alternative is to subclass the control's `WindowProc` property instead:

```
private
  FControl: TControl;
  FControlWndProc: TWndMethod;

procedure TMyLabel.Destroy;
begin
  SetControl(nil);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyLabel.SetControl(AControl: TControl);
begin
  if FControl <> AControl then
  begin
    if FControl <> nil then
    begin
      FControl.WindowProc := FControlWndProc;
      FControl.RemoveFreeNotification(Self);
    end;
    FControl := AControl;
    if FControl <> nil then
    begin
      FControlWndProc := FControl.WindowProc;
      FControl.WindowProc := ControlWndProc;
      FControl.FreeNotification(Self);
    end else
     FControlWndProc := nil;
    ...
  end;
end;

procedure TMyLabel.Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation);
begin
  inherited;
  if (Operation = opRemove) and (AComponent = FControl) then
  begin
    FControl := nil;
    FControlWndProc := nil;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyLabel.ControlWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  FControlWndProc(Message);
  // now check for position/size messages and reposition as needed...
end;
```

Comment: Hi Remy. Thanks for your answer! I tried the `subclass` solution, but it stucks on `FControlWndProc(Message);`. It seems that it enters a loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: "it seems like" does not necessary mean that it "is".  Use the debugger, what is it *actually* doing? What message(s) is it getting stuck on? The code is simply passing an intercepted message to the associated control for default handling, so there should be no looping unless either that control is itself generating new messages recursively, or your own code to position/size the label is having an effect on the control and causing it to generate new messages recursively.  Can you edit your question to show your actual code that is processing caught messages?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, There is something I don't understand: in the `SetControl` your second `if FControl <> nil then .. end else FControl.WindowProc := nil;` is that correct? shouldn't it be: `FControlWndProc := nil;`? Also, shouldn't you call `SetControl(nil)` both in the `TMyLabel.Notification` and both on `TMyLabel.Destroy`?

Comment: @kobik: That was a typo. It should have been `FControlWndProc` instead of `FControl.WindowProc`. And it does make sense to call `SetControl(nil)` in the destructor in case your label is freed before the control is freed, but it does not make sense to call it in `Notification()` since the control is being freed so there is no need to reset the control to its previous state, just reset the local tracking of it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I don't think it could hurt to reset the control to its previous state when the control is *being freed* - Has it already been free in that stage and wont need it's WindowProc? I'm not sure.

Comment: @kobik: Your label's `Notification()` will get called in the context of the associated control's destructor, after it has already destroyed its window (if it has one).

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I kinda liked this idea and writing my own TStickyLabel (I'll share it when/if I'm done) :) do you think it's safe to subclass the WindowProc in Design Mode (`csDesigning in ComponentState`)?

Comment: @kobik: yes, and you would have to if you want your label to follow the control as it is dragged around the designer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I have posted my code here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38047/tstickylabel-control-anyone

Answer (score 4):

Based on @RemyLebeau answer and some concept ideas from `ExtCtrls.TLabeledEdit` I have wrote my own [`TStickyLabel`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38047/tstickylabel-control-anyone) control. (Work in progress). Remy's answer should be accepted of-course :)